# Consuming from Kakfa topic and appending into list

Tags: python-3.x, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Currently I am trying to consume from a topic and appending all messages which comes out from a topic, but unfortunately the list in the end doesn't print anything.

```
import json
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'random_user_fetching',
    bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092',
    max_poll_records=100,
    value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m.decode('utf-8')),
    auto_offset_reset='earliest',
    enable_auto_commit=True,
    group_id='my_grp' 
)
print(consumer)
data_list=[]
try:
    for message in consumer:
        data = message.value
        data_list.append(data)
        consumer.commit()
        
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    pass

print(f"Processed messages: {len(data_list)}")
print(data_list)
consumer.close()
```

Output as below
`<kafka.consumer.group.KafkaConsumer object at 0x7f1c3379c9d0>`

Any comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code seems Okay. Could you please add some logging or print statements within the loop like below to see if any exceptions are being raised. This can help you identify if there are any issues during message consumption.

```
import json
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'random_user_fetching',
    bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092',
    max_poll_records=100,
    value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m.decode('utf-8')),
    auto_offset_reset='earliest',
    enable_auto_commit=True,
    group_id='my_grp' 
)
print(consumer)
data_list = []

try:
    for message in consumer:
        data = message.value
        data_list.append(data)
        print(f"Received message: {data}")
        consumer.commit()
        
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    pass

print(f"Processed messages: {len(data_list)}")
print(data_list)
consumer.close()
```

-----------UPDATE---------

Try below logic: the loop will break after consuming the specified number of messages `(max_messages)`. This way, you should be able to see the printed output outside the loop once the loop terminates. Adjust the condition according

```
import json
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'random_user_fetching',
    bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092',
    max_poll_records=100,
    value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m.decode('utf-8')),
    auto_offset_reset='earliest',
    enable_auto_commit=True,
    group_id='my_grp' 
)

print(consumer)
data_list = []
max_messages = 100  # Set a limit on the number of messages to consume

try:
    for message in consumer:
        data = message.value
        data_list.append(data)
        print(f"Received message: {data}")
        consumer.commit()

        # Break out of the loop after consuming a certain number of messages
        if len(data_list) >= max_messages:
            break
        
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    pass

print(f"Processed messages: {len(data_list)}")
print(data_list)
consumer.close()
```

Comment: I had already tested. That one work. It prints the value when we do it in the for loop. Nothing print if I try to print outside of for.

Comment: @VarunSharma, you may need to break out of the loop. One way to do this is by setting a condition to break out of the loop after a certain number of messages or after a specific event.

Comment: Make sense. It is waiting for polled messages to complete and then it goes into the list.